# What font is this and where can I find it?

Tags: fonts, font-identification, font-recommendation

What is this font [image]? If it is not standard, what would you say is the closest font?

Comment: [Otis Condensed](https://www.myfonts.com/products/otis-condensed-otis-condensed-86291?queryId=ec1b09fba45710534bb96b08f4d0c80c&index=universal_search_data&objectIDs=5430676002) is not a million miles away, but the W is different.

Answer (score 1):

This one I don't recognize and it could well be custom lettering, but look through the [Handbuch der Schiftarten](https://www.klingspor-museum.de/Handbuch-der-Schriftarten.html), an index of German metal types. The Klingspor has digitized it. If you find it's a typeface, Google it and look for digitizations. Myself sadly I don't have time to do this now. I've answered questions in this way before.

If nothing comes up, this type seems mostly to have the feel of a contrasted or stressed or modulated sans-serif: a sans-serif for which the thin strokes are much thinner than the thick strokes. (It has serifs but they're kinda tiny, so I think this is the main feel of how the design looks.) These types were quite popular around the start of the twentieth century from German and British foundries.

My guess is that Britannic (despite the name, originally designed in Leipzig, Germany) would be a reasonable match. There are various digitizations. [Kris Sowersby's Domaine Sans](https://klim.co.nz/collections/domaine-sans/) also. Both have a bit of nineteenth-century flavor. [Jonathan Hoefler once said](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7VnFNooWgD0) that contrasted sans-serifs are the "eccentric relatives" of type design, with a lot of way-out varieties (check out the video for examples), but this feels quite traditional and late nineteenth/early twentieth-century in feel.

Comment: Thanks for the references. It could be something like the Alt-Romanisch font on page 109 of the Handbuch der Schriftarten, but maybe not quite. Not sure I can find it, but good starting point.